# How to update select2 drop down in codeigniter

Tags: jquery, codeigniter, jquery-select2

Hi i am using **select2** **jquery** plugin to **insert** multiple values to a drop down but when i am trying to update i am facing problem can anyone help me out in showing the right way of doing this

```
<?php 
    $cats = explode(',',$r['keyword_whomtoteach']);
    foreach($cats as  $vald) {
        foreach($keyword as $key=>$keywords) { 
            if ($vald == $keywords->keyword_id) { ?>                         
                <option value="<?php echo $keywords->keyword_id; ?>" <?php { echo "selected"; }  ?>><?php echo $keywords->keyword_name; ?></option> <?php } else { ?>
                <option value="<?php echo $keywords->keyword_id; ?>"><?php echo $keywords->keyword_name; ?></option>  
<?php        }  
        }
    }
?>
```

I am trying to do something like this i am getting values but the unsaved values which are comming from second  is taking alot of time to load data its very slow can i know how to fix this .

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $(".selectmultiple").select2();
    });
</script>

public function keyword_all()
{
    $this->db->select('*')->from('keywords');
    $query=$this->db->get();
    return $keyword = $query->result();
}
```

this is the model from which i am looping `foreach($keyword as $key=>$keywords)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if this solves your problem but this could make things a bit quicker - it's certainly a lot neater.

```
<?php 
    $cats = explode(',', $r['keyword_whomtoteach']);
    foreach($cats as $vald) {
        foreach($keyword as $key=>$keywords) { ?>                    
            <option value="<?php echo $keywords->keyword_id; ?>" <?=($vald == $keywords->keyword_id ? 'selected' : '')?> ><?php echo $keywords->keyword_name; ?></option> 
<?php   }
    }
?>
```

Comment: It's still slow :( is there any other way i should do this ? @dinosaurHunter

Comment: It's a big drop down with around 700 array

Comment: one more problem i am getting while using your code is if i am having 3 element in array 367,368,369 then it is repeating 3 times 367,368,369,367,368,369,367,368,369 while saving would i be able to save only 367,368,369 @DinosaurHunter

Comment: but your way is far better than me thanks just help me out in saving only unique id's not repeating ? @DinosaurHunter

Comment: i fixed it with your code and with the help of JavaScript removed repetition btw Thanks