# how to display select2 values in dropdown list using codeigniter?

Tags: php, html, mysql, codeigniter

I need to display the select2 values into my dropdown listbox using codeigniter framework in php.
for ex:
1)Dr. Abhay Nene 
2)Dr. Ajoy Shetty

i have selected this name already. it showing in the list . but it not showing in the list as selected.

```
<select class="multiple-select2 form-control" name="reviwerid[]" multiple="multiple" id="userRequest_activity" required>                                        
    <?php
        $cats = explode(',', $res->abstract_reviewerid);
        print_r($cats);
        echo $count_no = count($cats);
        foreach($cats as $vald)
        {                                               
            foreach($reviewresults as $reviewresult)
            {
                if($reviewresult->reviewer_name != "")
                { ?>
                <option <?php ($vald == $reviewresult->reviewer_id) ? 'selected=' : '') ?> value="<?php echo $reviewresult->reviewer_id; ?>">
                <?php echo $reviewresult->reviewer_name; ?></option>        
    <?php }
            }
        } ?>
</select>

please help me how to do this?

thanks in advance...!

[1]: https://i.s
```

this my php code:
                tack.imgur.com/0K31f.jpg

Comment: Have you used select2?

Comment: What is your question? The code is not working? Select2 si just simple js library that works with `<select>`  tag.

Comment: Check this fiddle. It might help you:http://jsfiddle.net/jEADR/62/

Comment: i want to show the selected value in dropdown list. Also i have posted my image in my blog.https://shahulblog.blogspot.in/ please help me im a beginner in ci

Comment: i think you asking to display the values as selected dynamically?

Comment: dont use shortcode instead

Comment: please refer image blog link.  shahulblog.blogspot.in please check the selected list i have mention in image

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to update select2 drop down in codeigniter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37131953/how-to-update-select2-drop-down-in-codeigniter)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.5/css/select2.min.css' />

<select multiple id="e1" style="width:400px">
    <option value="1">Dr. Abhay Nene</option>
    <option value="2">Dr. Ajoy Shetty</option>
</select>

<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.5/js/select2.full.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $("#e1").select2();
</script>
```

Comment: It is not a static value. all are dynamic value

Comment: This is an example you can set your dynamic value in it.

Comment: Also i have refer this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37131953/how-to-update-select2-drop-down-in-codeigniter